# JWT token role claim translated wrong by DOTNET

Tags: .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, claims

I have a Dotnet core 6 Web Api that is receiving requests with JWT Tokens containing, among others, a role claim in the payload, like this:

```
{ "role": "SOME_ROLE" }
```

Now, I was unable to read from the User object (ClaimsPrincipal) this role. I did not have the same problem with other claims, just the role one, until I found that the problem was that instead of having the role named like in the token ("role"), it was renamed to "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role". That was the reason I could not find it. Does anyone know how to avoid this renaming and leave as it is in the Token?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net core can automatic mapping some claims, You can add this configuration in Program.cs(Net 6) to avoid this

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

There are more details in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0), You can refer to it.